# Adding a new row css table-less layout

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a table-less design using div and css. I have successfully made the header part. But after the header I have some text part which was supposed to be coming inside a div. However the div is displayed as inline and does not contain the text elements.

The code that I am trying is available at http://jsfiddle.net/sXaTT/1/

What I need is the 'Join our community' and 'FB Like' block should be inside the main container.

This is my first attempt to make a table-less design. Any help to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to read more on this to be honest, that layout is a bit of a disaster. You're containing your main div (which I assume is the content) inside of your header container. Either that or your naming conventions really need work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would change my naming convention. This is my first table-less design.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, personally I would get my containers in position before worrying about anything else at all. Create each area and set it a different background color only. No need to worry about fonts, borders absolutely nothing until you get your containers sitting where you want them. It makes your CSS easier to read and trouble shoot. And read about grid systems, they're a bit tough to figure out in the beginning but they'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve

```
.main{
  width:380px; margin:0 auto;
  border:1px green solid;
  position:relative;
  padding:0px;
  background:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXaTT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I have not changed the CSS just moved the div containing the fb link etc... Is this what you mean? [filddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXaTT/3/)

Comment: Thank you for looking into my issue. afshin's answer was the one I was looking for.